# Can 2 Wi-Fi adapters work with a single antenna?

Tags: ieee-802.11

I have a panel Wi-Fi antenna and an adapter for it. These 2 work flawlessly together. But also I would like to connect to somewhere else without buying another huge antenna. Is it possible if these 2 APs are in the same location? There are antenna cable splitters in the web like this:

[image: antenna splitter]

Comment: In a word -- NO.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The adapter you have pictured looks like a simple T peice. This will create horrible impedance mismatches and will also expose the receiver of one adapter to nearly the full transmit power of the other.

If you insist on doing this then you should get a [proper power splitter](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ZX10-2-42-S%2B), something like  should do the trick. Even then you may well find that the two adapters interfere with each other, the splitter provides some isolation, but nowhere near as much as using seperate antennas would. I would also add a [DC block](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=BLK-89-S%2B) in the line to one of the wifi adapters in case the adapters have DC connections to their antenna connectors.

Finally note that using wi-fi gear with directional antennas without turning down the transmit power is likely to be a violation of radio regulations.